# What is the java representation of size in matlab

Tags: java, arrays, matlab

This is the size function defined in Matlab as seen in the docs:

```
m = size(X,dim) returns the size of the dimension of X specified by scalar dim.
```

1) Given that X is an single array in java, how would I replicate this method using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab just stores matrix and n-dimensional data linearly in an array. Each dimension's size is saved along with the array, so Matlab knows which element to return when you index not linearly (e.g. `A(3,5)` for a 5x5 matrix, Matlab knows it should return element `A(23)` which is `3+(5-1)*5`).

So in java if an array has size `N1xN2x...xNN`, and your looking for element: `(X1,X2,...,XN)`, you should find element with position: `X1+(X2-1)*N1+(X3-1)*N1*N2+ ... +(XN-1)*NN-1*..*N1` in the array...

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the size of the array(any dimention), you have an attribute `Array.length`.

From [**JLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> The public final field length, which contains the number of components
>   of the array. length may be positive or zero.

Eg:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
int length = arr.length; //would obtain 10
```

Answer (score 0):

An array in Java only has one dimension: the number of elements. You can access this simply by using the property `Array.length`.  For more complex containers (such as `ArrayList`) you can often use the member-function `size()`.

```
int[] array = new int[5];
int arrayLength = array.length; //arrayLength == 5

ArrayList<int> arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.add(1);
arrayList.add(2);
int arrayListLength = arrayLis.size(); //arrayListLength == 2
```